# get APDU request error c++

Tags: c++, smartcard, apdu

So .. I have pcsc-reader, smartcard and c++ code.
Find readers, chose them, connect and get ATR - working greatfull.

but after ATR-get i need to get APDU request, this code

```
SCARD_IO_REQUEST ioRecv;
byte  pbRecvBuffer[255]; 
int pbRecvLength=255;
byte   pbSendBuffer[] ={ 0x00, 0xb0, 0x00, 0x00}; //any comand
int cbSendLength = sizeof(pbSendBuffer);//size of comand
ioRecv.cbPciLength = 255;
DWORD  dwSize=255; 

//our Transmit those return error
lReturn = SCardTransmit(hSC,
                        (LPCSCARD_IO_REQUEST)dwAP,
                        pbSendBuffer,
                cbSendLength,
                        NULL,
                        pbRecvBuffer,
                        &dwSize);

if(lReturn==SCARD_S_SUCCESS){
//do smt with pbRecvBuffer   
printf("success");
}
else {
    printf("error "); 
}
```

always return   "error"...
If you could help me or point out my error, I would be very grateful.

Thank you

Comment: Error was found in  first param of SCardTransmit() - According to the description of MSDN in SCardTransmit () does not need to pass a hSC. so have to pass m_hCardHandle received from SCardConnect (). also it wrong to pass (LPCSCARD_IO_REQUEST)dwAP.

Comment: So did this solve your error? If so, post it as an answer for posterity. You may even accept your own answers after a while, although you won't get points for it (I will vote up though).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Error was found in first param of SCardTransmit() - According to the
>   description of MSDN in SCardTransmit () does not need to pass a hSC.
>   so have to pass m_hCardHandle received from SCardConnect (). also it
>   wrong to pass (LPCSCARD_IO_REQUEST)dwAP

yap. It have solve the problem